# Android How to start another class

Tags: java, android, class

I already tried to start another class using this code:

```
startService(new Intent(this, Client.class));
```

And this one:

```
Intent GIntent = new Intent(this, Client.class);
GIntent.setAction(Client.class.getSimpleName());
startService(GIntent);
```

But none of them works.

The onstart in Client.class is as followed:

```
public void onStart() {
  
  Log.e(TAG, "!! Started successfully !!"); ...
```

But also not even the log-message appears. Does someone know where I made a mistake?
It get logs before and after the startservice action, but not from the other class itself.

The manifest contains the followed for the Client. There arent any errors. And yes, it is a service, not an activity.

```
<service android:name=".Client">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name=".Client" />
     </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Is all classes in `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: Are you trying to start a `Service` or an `Activity`? Also, does it crash? If so, post the stacktrace

Comment: <service android:name=".Client">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name=".Client" />
      </intent-filter>
 </service>

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to start a `Service`, than in the `Service` class you're interested in the methods `onCreate()` and `onStartCommand()`. The former is obviously called when the `Service` is initially created, the latter is created if the service already exists. Note that the `onStart()` method of the `Service` class is deprecated and shouldn't be used.

If the `Client.class` is an `Activity`, than be sure to start it with `startActivity()` and not `startService()`.

Both the `Activity` and `Service` should be declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.